# Strange 9-patch behaviour

Tags: android, button, background, selector, nine-patch

I've come across an issue with a 9-patch button background and I can't figure out what I'm doing wrong.

This is the xml configuration for the button:

```
<Button android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:id="@+id/buttonBack"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true" android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:padding="2dp" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/selector_bg_back_button" android:text="@string/back"
        android:textColor="#ffffff" android:textStyle="bold"
        android:layout_marginLeft="2dp" />
```

In this config, I'm using a selector so that the background is different when the button is pressed (the same 9-patch, only in greyscale). I've also tried using the nine-patch directly, without the selector, and it appears to make no difference.

This is the 9-patch image:
[image: nine-patch]

And this is the result:
[image]

As you can see, the padding and stretching areas  appear to be completely ignored.
I have the impression that it's using the 9-patch image as a plain png, but I can't figure out why. Any help would be appreciated because this is starting to get on my nerves :p

Thanks in advance.

**Edit**

Ok so this is the full layout in which I'm using the button.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:orientation="vertical">
<RelativeLayout android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:background="#0ab0ed" android:layout_height="40dip"
    android:padding="0px">
    <Button android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:id="@+id/buttonBack"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true" android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:padding="2dp" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/btn_bg_back_blue" android:text="@string/back"
        android:textColor="#ffffff" android:textStyle="bold"
        android:layout_marginLeft="2dp" />
    <ImageView android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent" android:src="@drawable/logo"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />
</RelativeLayout>
<RelativeLayout android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:padding="10dp" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="#f5f5f5">
    <ImageView android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="10dp" android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:id="@+id/image" />
    <TextView android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:id="@+id/txtTitle"
        android:textColor="#182973" android:textSize="16dp"
        android:textStyle="bold" android:gravity="center_horizontal" />
</RelativeLayout>
<RelativeLayout android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:background="#ffffff">
    <TextView android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true" android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:id="@+id/txtDate" style="@style/content" />
    <ScrollView android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent">
        <WebView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            android:id="@+id/webview" android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent" />
    </ScrollView>
</RelativeLayout>
```

And code-wise, there isn't much I can show you. All I do is add a very simple listener to the button:

```
Button back = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonBack);
    back.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            finish();
        }
    });
```

Comment: Are you using a ".9.png" suffix for the filename?

Comment: Put this into a project. Worked fine! Looks like the problem could be elsewhere, could you expose more code?

Comment: I edited the post to include the full layout and the code where I use this button. As you can see, there's really not a lot going on there, which is part of the reason why I find it so strange that it doesn't work properly ... I'm really doing nothing special here.

Comment: Have you tried making a clean>build? Unrelated: Why the hell would you like to implement an back button on an Android Device?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the button **actually is** that size, and the background + size of the containing `RelativeLayout` makes you think otherwise. You don't actually need to use the button widget. You can set the background of the `RelativeLayout` to your button's background and implement an `OnClickListener`. Add a `TextView` and `ImageView` to it to get your desired look.

Answer (score 0):

Both your button and your imageview have layout_width set to WRAP_CONTENT, so they won't be larger than the original size and thus your 9-patch won't be stretched.